# Youtube API: Revert video thumbnail to the default thumbnail

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to revert the thumbnail of youtube videos, via the v3 API, to the thumbnail that is automatically generated by YouTube from a screenshot of the video when it's uploaded.

So, basically, I wanna delete the custom thumbnail I uploaded.

The documentation, as far as I can tell, only shows how to set a new thumbnail by uploading an Image, but has nothing on how to delete/revert thumbnails.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/thumbnails/set

Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is that you grab one of the three automatically generated thumbnails:

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/{video_id}/1.jpg
http://img.youtube.com/vi/{video_id}/2.jpg
http://img.youtube.com/vi/{video_id}/3.jpg
```

You could then upload either of them via the API. Unfortunately, they are in very poor quality. Maybe there is a way to get a high-quality version of them?

Comment: I tried that but the quality is too poor :( And couldn't figure out how to get them in a better quality

Answer (score 0):

you can use this below url too, It gives you a good quality thumbnail

```
https://ytimg.googleusercontent.com/vi/{VIDEO_ID}/mqdefault.jpg
```

Actually You cannot get the other images at full size. Only /0.jpg or default image is large rest will be in thumbnail size.

Comment: But it gives me the current thumbnail, and what I want is to revert the video to one of the three thumbnails YT creates from screenshots of the video when you upload it.

Comment: @dietbacon I have changed the answer